# Nextjs project deployment on Vercel failed without any details or build logs

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy a new NextJs project on Vercel but the deployment is failing and I can't seem to figure out what the error is as there is not any kind of error message or build logs as to why the deployment failed.
[image: Vercel deployment failed screenshot]

I am getting nothing except the message "Deployment failed with error" as seen in the image above without pointing me to what went wrong.

Also I'm getting this from my github repo that all checks have failed but no details provided and clicking on the details link redirects me to a 404 page on vercel:

[image: Github error]

Any ideas on about what is going on and how to fix this?

Comment: are you deploying with git integration

Comment: @Yilmaz Yes, I am.

Comment: looks like there is config error. You either changed build command or folder structure is not right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Vercel support:

> Our team was made aware of the issue and have published a fix about
> this problem earlier this week.

Now you should be able to see the build logs.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The build logs are now available and I was able to deploy successfully after rectifying the errors found in build logs.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795708/cant-open-the-build-logs-when-vercel-deploy-fails-at-first-try

Both should be resolved! Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi @leerob, yes the issue has been resolved now.

Comment: I have this issue now