# Can't open the Build logs when Vercel deploy fails at first try

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy a NextJs application to Vercel.
I followed steps in this tutorial: https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-prisma-postgres and the deploy with that app works but with my new app doesn't.

On localhost my application runs just fine but when I'm trying to deploy on Vercel the deploy fails with message **Deployment failed with error.**
I'm trying to get the logs, to see why the deploy failed but I can't click on the **Building** part of the screen where I could see the build logs.
Picture of Vercel after Deploy failed:

[image]

My question is how could I see the logs if the Vercel deploy fails at first try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue with 0 error code to go on...

Comment: Hey, Lee from Vercel here. Are you still having an error here? If you can provide the error stack, I can help investigate.

Comment: Hi, I still have the error and I can't show the stack trace because the Vercel website dont lets me click on 'Building' part so I can't see the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I couldn't deploy my app in Vercel and none error showed on the console. So, I run the `npm run build` locally and there it showed me some typescript errors that don't appear in any other place. After I solved those errors I could deploy my app in Vercel without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into it further, and to get some error information I used the vercel cli (https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/overview) instead of gui.
Hope this helps you to.